# How can I get a CMYK colour from a pdf?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, ghostscript, cmyk

I need to detect the CMYK colour of some text in a pdf. Just like you can with Acrobat's Print Production/Output Preview feature, but via a vb.net program.

I've used Ghostcript's inkcov command in the past to do something similar and get the CMYK value of ink coverage in a specified area of a pdf, but I can't seem to find a way to list the individual different CMYK values this way.

I've tried using SpirePDF to get the co-ordinates of the text and then producing a bitmap from the area, and then looping through the pixels to get the RGB values, but I can't get a CMYK value this way. Trying to convert the RGB to CMYK doesn't produce a close enough match to the original colour, so I think I have to stick with working directly on the pdf.

Using Ghostcript to isolate the area I'm interested in, I can probably produce a pdf with just some text in the colour I want to find, plus the background colour, but how do I get the text colour from that stage?

Or is there an easier approach?

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I did see that and looked through, but didn't seem to be what I wanted?

Comment: The text might not be specified in a CMYK colour space. It could be RGB, Lab or an ICCBased colour, or even a Separation or DeviceN (though in that case it would have an Alternate Device space. You could render it to a CMYK composite using eg the tiff32nc or psdcmyk devices if you have a tool which will read CMYK output files. Or you could produce separated CMYK files, 8 BPP. Then you can get the CMYK values from each plane. Those will of course be 0->255 so some mapping will be required if you need a percentage. I'd decompress the PDF file and look at the colour used by the text.

Comment: OK, looks like I need to dig a bit deeper and there isn't a simple solution. Thanks for posting.